# How to expand an object along a curve without destroying the mesh and just follows the shape of the curve?

Tags: bezier-curves, vertex-groups, path

I'm trying to recreate a sphere with selected vertex and expanding it along a curve seems like stretching the sphere. I know it's possible with metaballs and using particles but it's not as smooth like with a simple mesh. Wht modifier should i be using? I have tried follow path and curve with selected vertex groups. Using Blender 2.79
P.S. If it is also possible with a bezier curve bevel with a circle if I can adjust where I would like the the bezier curve be affected by the bevel it would also help... The only thing I can think of is cheating it with a boolean if it is a box but with a spehere or any other objects I don't think it will work...

Comment: Related? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134087/generate-mesh-using-boolean-modifier-over-time/162307#162307