# How to animate deforming scratches?

Tags: animation, modifiers, displacement

I would like to create the following animation: one mesh scrapes the other.

I think the best option is to animate the boolean modifier, but the boolean difference disappears as the object moves. I would like the difference remain to make it look like a scratch.

[image]

The next idea was to use dynamic paint (displacement), but it leaves a lot of "artifacts", I believe due to dragging the outer vertex?

[image]

Could you suggest me other solutions that may work as intended?
I tried searching for it on the internet but with no luck so far.

Edit: The above examples are simple, but what about more complicated scratches?
[image]

Comment: Hello, what is the mesh density of your bigger cube ? (ie how subdivided is it ?)

Comment: Hi, I did this just for an example and did not care about the resolution, it's just for the illustration. I'm looking for solution that starts carving in one edge of object and ends on the other edge. Dynamic paint works great when you start somewhere in the center of the object, pushing vertex to the inside like here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kcy_KBCsx70. But when you start from the edge it drags the outer vertex making something like artifacts.

Comment: I once made a couple of suggestions in answer to a similar question, [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/120193/35559).. I wouldn't know how suitable they are..

Answer (score 1):

If you inset a plane, so the inner quad has vertex normals going up, and then assign a new material to that quad only, and in the material use vertex color as displacement, you get something that looks like a cube. You can scale down the ring around the displaced quad, or you can assign a transparent material to these faces. Then subdivide the inner quad **a lot**, add the dynamic paint canvas, and add a dynamic paint brush to the small cube with which you scrape off material. I get no artifacts, but again in order to get somewhat smooth results, I had to subdivide a lot:

[image]

[GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoVVx.gif)

Answer (score 0):

In the first example why not use a rectangle instead of a square for the boolean so the backside is longer and doesn't disappear as it goes over the bottom cube. You could animate lots of strange shapes for options.

You may also want to do something like in the unrelated answer to this question here:

[Animating appearing/extending strip with gaps](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63310/animating-appearing-extending-strip-with-gaps/63322#63322)