# Animate an object being shaped in a mill or something similar

Tags: animation, modifiers

I want to animate two objects intersecting. When object A intersects object B I want to cut out the intersecting part of object A. I have tried the boolean modifier but the intersecting parts reappear, when the emerge from object B. Maybe I could do something by making object A non rigid and really soft...[image: This is an image during animation, the part intersecting the "walls" are only temporarily gone]
Here you can see an object whose intersecting parts with the corridor are only gone while they are intersecting. What I actually want is that any part that ever intersects with the corridors is removed from the moving mesh.
Another problem is that I can't build object A from multiple meshes which disappear when I need them to because I'd like a dynamic solution which always works when completed
Sorry if this is a stupid question but I am still fairly new to animating in Blender.

Comment: hello, it would help if you showed some screenshots of your objects etc...

Comment: I hope it is better now with the added image

Comment: you could create an invisible object that will keep the cut part?

Comment: Not a stupid question, but a hard problem for sure. Related: [How can I create a boolean mesh to replicate the movement of a milling bit?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/120193/60486)